# ACRA causes app to delay start

Tags: android, acra

I'm using `ACRA` in my Android app. When initializing the app in the `onCreate()` of my `Application` class, there is a visible delay before the app starts. This shows as a white screen before the first layout of the app displays.

Is there a way to get around this ?? Maybe load a content view in the `Application` class or initialize `ACRA` later in the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also integrate the Acra in my apps, but i never came across the issue you mentioned here. Following is how I am initializing the Acra:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate() 
    {
        // The following line triggers the initialization of ACRA
        ACRA.init(this);
        super.onCreate();
    }
```

Comment: Hmmm...maybe but if I clear everything in the first activity. There is still a delay. Is there a way to check if ACRA is causing this ??

Comment: OK... just realized that is stupid. I can just comment it out.

Comment: First of all, write this code in Application class's onCreate() method. If that does not work, try commenting the ACRA.init() method and check if you are facing the same issue without ACRA. I dont think that ACRA can cause this.

Comment: @Saad :) Its fine, it happens

Comment: Its fine. Are you calling any webservice or database stuff in the first activity? If yes, then it may be the reason after your issue. Try writing all those code in AsyncTask and display a ProgressDialog untill the data loads. I hope it help you.

Comment: Nah... I commented out everything. The app doesn't even load... just shows the first screen background.... maybe its allocating memory or something

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12242/discussion-between-shraddha-and-saad-farooq)